# Java, what does "cannot find symbol" mean?

Tags: java

I have some java code:

NameTest.java:

```
public class NameTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Name = myName = new Name("John", "Smith", "Doe");  //This is Line 6
        Name = wifeName = new Name ("Jane", "Smith");
        Name = single = new Name ("Smith");
        Name someName;
        System.out.println ("myName: " + myName.toString());
    }
}
```

Error Message I get:

```
    *~/Java1/Section5$ java -cp. Name.java NameTest.java
Unrecognized option: -cp.
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
~/Java1/Section5$ javac NameTest.java
NameTest.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Name
location: class NameTest
        Name = myName = new Name("John", "Smith", "Doe");
        ^
NameTest.java:6: cannot find symbol
```

What does `NameTest.java:6: cannot find symbol` mean?

Comment: That's not your code causing the problem. Your java install is messed up. Look at the first line of the error.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson: later 4th line you can see, it has Compilation errors and not java installation issues.

Comment: @Jayesh ok. But do we really need 3 answers saying the exact same thing.

Comment: Notice that there must be a `space` between `-cp` and `.`, else it will take `-cp.` as the option, which is not valid. Also, do a separate compilation of your source files. First `Name.java`, and then `NameTest.java`, to make things simpler for you.

Comment: That's true, even I was about to give answer then saw somebody gave so I ignored mine.

Answer (score 2):

you have a syntax error

```
Name = myName = new Name("John", "Smith", "Doe");
```

should be

```
Name myName = new Name("John", "Smith", "Doe");
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Name = myName = new Name("John", "Smith", "Doe");
```

Use

```
Name  myName = new Name("John", "Smith", "Doe");
```

`=` is an [assignment operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) in java which assigns the RHS value to LHS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this syntax:

```
Name = single = new Name ("Smith");
```

Instead,

```
Name single = new Name ("Smith");
```

Fixing all of these will clear your current list of exceptions (the last one will be fixed once myName becomes a valid reference).